# How to bind a column in DataGrid to more than one column in Data source?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have:

- DataTable with three columns: `Id`, `FName`, `LName`.
- Data Grid with two columns: `Id`, `Full Name`. Where `Full Name` column is combination of `FName` and `LName`.

How can the `Full Name` column of DataGrid can be bound to two Data Source columns (`FName` and `LName`) without any string manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new column to the datatable

e.g.:

```
        private void DGTest_gridBind()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("FName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("LName", typeof(string));

        table.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string), "FName + ' ' + LName");

        table.Rows.Add("Jack", "Miller");
        table.Rows.Add("Sam", "Tucker");

        DGTest.DataSource = table;
```

}